# Delete all the content from file

Tags: ruby

I want to remove the content form the list of files.

EDIT :

I have list of files.

file1
file2
file3

Those file containing bunch of lines ...

I want to remove all the lines from each files.

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: @Timo. It sounds like he has a list of files and he wants to remove/delete their content. That was clear from the first revision. If he's posting here, he probably wants to know how that can be achieved. Not everyone here speaks english fluently.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Looks like you need to truncate file.
Do something like:

```
File.open('/tmp/file', 'w') {|file| file.truncate(0) }
```

Comment: `File.open('/tmp/file', 'w') {}` should be enough.

Comment: `truncate` is also available as a class method, there is no need to explicitly open the file: `File.truncate('/path/to/file', 0)`. Note, however, that this is documented as "Not available on all platforms." (Which usually means POSIX only, i.e. no JRuby, no IronRuby, no Windows.)

Comment: `File.truncate('/path/to/file', 0)` does work on JRuby, at least on Mac and Linux

Answer (score 30):

To truncate a file:

```
File.truncate('/path/to/file', 0)
```

To truncate list of files:

```
[file1, file2, file3].each { |file| File.truncate(file, 0) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since truncate is not available on all platforms, use `f = open('filename', File::TRUNC) {}`

Comment: If you actually want to write to the file as well, do: `f = open('filename', File::TRUNC | File::WRONLY) {}`.